# Difference between colspan and column-span in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## colspan:

```
<td colspan="4"> 
</td>
```

### column-span

```
<td style="column-span:4"> 
</td>
```

The `colspan` does working properly. but `column-span` does not working.

---

I have little bit confusion with the full name :

because **`colspan`** full name is `column span`. but `column-span` is different from `colspan`.

> - Please explain the meaning of `colspan` and `column-span`
> - And tell me the difference.

Comment: Note: Browser support for `column-span:` is poor. Avoid using it. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`column-span:` was designed for print-style layouts and is a pure CSS rule. It is used to span CSS `columns` (not table columns).

`colspan` the *attribute* is used for table `TD` elements to get them to span multiple columns in the table.

Note: Browser support for `column-span:` is poor. Avoid using it. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp

Comment: Okay. why the `row-span` is not available in html?

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran: Because `column` layouts, for print, do not have rows! Like newspaper columns, they are not laid out in a grid, but just flow from one column to the next :)